# How to score MathNode?

Tags: discussion, scoring

MathNode is a graphical language made by myself with an interpreter currently not publicized, so I'm asking this ahead of time. In MathNode, surprise surprise! You have nodes. These nodes can be connected to each other to perform calculations. Here is a screeshot showcasing some things it can do:
[image: Some MathNode features]

So basically it can do arithmetic operations, recursion (wires can connect to themselves), and node movement which is just a side effect and doesn't do anything although it can be used to show output.

It also supports input by clicking nodes, and a few other things.

So what would be the best way to score this language in [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenges?

Comment: Closely related, possible duplicate: [How to determine the length of a Piet program?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10996/12012)

Comment: Also: [There's a new graphical language- how to score it?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7711/12012)

Answer (score 4):

By the number of bytes that are required to store your program on disk. That is the only thing that makes sense for challenges that are scored in *bytes*.

Comment: But it's a graphical language (I forgot to mention that in the question, although it should be clear looking at the image)

Comment: I know. There is no (good) reason to score graphical languages in a special way. Bytes are bytes.

Comment: So, the image of the nodes on disk? How is that fair? Look at Minecraft for example (Yes, there are submissions that use it). Would you score it by the amount of bytes in the save file?

Comment: You have a language that *you* are making. You can make the nodes-to-bytes conversion as efficient as you want. There's nothing unfair about it.

Comment: @FireCubez You can assume competitions are between that language only. If you're using any language that are not a golfing language, you drop the chance of winning already, so don't worry about it.